# Adding fakes for an assembly fails without any error messages

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5, microsoft-fakes

I am trying to setup some unit testing for a connector assembly that communicates with a web service. I was following along with an example provided:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/atverma/archive/2012/05/03/unit-test-a-project-having-external-dependency-wcf-proxy-using-fakes-amp-visual-studio-11-beta.aspx

However, when I add fakes for my connector assembly, the project fails to build and no errors are reported. So, I modified the fakes file to turn on diagnostic and use noisy verbosity... and still received no error messages. Then I disabled BOTH stub and shim generation in the fakes file, and it STILL failed to build.

If i remove the fakes for my connector assembly, it builds. I add fakes for it, the project does not build. Without getting any error messages, I have no idea how to make this work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've never seen a build fail with no errors...

Comment: Please submit your repro project at http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio

Answer (score 0):

Put the Diagnostic to false for the mean time.

```
<Fakes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011/">
  <Assembly Name="Namespace here" Version="1.4.4731.18265"/>
</Fakes>
```